# Difficulty debugging rails app when parsing value of radio button input and saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to take a string value from a form (like `"890-UPS Standard"`) and parse it into two fields in my database (`order.shipping` gets the numeric price, `order.shipping_choice` gets the string for the shipping method).

I have the following form situation in my app on my `charges#shipping` view:

```
    <% shipping_choices = [] %>
    <% @ups_rates.each do |rate| %>
      <% choice = [] %>
      <% choice << rate[1].to_s + "-" + rate[0].to_s %> <!-- value -->
      <% choice << number_to_currency(rate[1]/100).to_s + " - " + rate[0].to_s %>
      <% shipping_choices << choice %>
    <% end %>
  <%= simple_form_for @order, url: charges_update_order_path(:shipping), method: :post do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-inputs text-left">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :shipping, shipping_choices, :first, :last, item_wrapper_class: :block_radio_button_collection %>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- form inputs -->
    </div> <!-- choices row -->
    <div class="row">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Calculate Shipping" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

There is a method in my `order.rb` model which should the value and turn it into the appropriate formats:

```
  def update_order_from_shipping_page(shipping_pair)
    self.shipping = shipping_pair.gsub(/[^\d]/, '').to_f
    self.shipping_choice = shipping_pair.gsub(/\A[a-z\s]+\Z/, '')
    new_total = self.total + shipping
    self.update_attributes(total: new_total, shipping_choice: self.shipping_choice)
  end
```

Here is the HTML generated by the form, just so it is clear what's going on:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <span class="block_radio_button_collection"><label for="order_shipping_1820-ups_ground"><input type="radio" value="1820-UPS Ground" name="order[shipping]" id="order_shipping_1820-ups_ground" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="order_shipping_1820-ups_ground">$18.00 - UPS Ground</label></label></span>
    <span class="block_radio_button_collection"><label for="order_shipping_4292-ups_three-day_select"><input type="radio" value="4292-UPS Three-Day Select" name="order[shipping]" id="order_shipping_4292-ups_three-day_select" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="order_shipping_4292-ups_three-day_select">$42.00 - UPS Three-Day Select</label></label></span>
    <span class="block_radio_button_collection"><label for="order_shipping_6673-ups_second_day_air"><input type="radio" value="6673-UPS Second Day Air" name="order[shipping]" id="order_shipping_6673-ups_second_day_air" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="order_shipping_6673-ups_second_day_air">$66.00 - UPS Second Day Air</label></label></span>
    <span class="block_radio_button_collection"><label for="order_shipping_13851-ups_next_day_air_saver"><input type="radio" value="13851-UPS Next Day Air Saver" name="order[shipping]" id="order_shipping_13851-ups_next_day_air_saver" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="order_shipping_13851-ups_next_day_air_saver">$138.00 - UPS Next Day Air Saver</label></label></span>
</div>
```

I am currently getting a `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error on my `update_order` method in my `charges_controller`:

```
  def update_order
    @order = current_order
    if @order.update_order_from_shipping_page(params[:order][:shipping][:shipping_choice])
      redirect_to new_charge_path and return
    else
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:notice] = "Something is amuck."
    end
  end
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Take a look at your params, in update_order, in the debugger. Make sure it has the structure you expect. :shipping_choice, in particular. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was using one too many parameters, so it began working when I changed `(params[:order][:shipping][:shipping_choice])` to `(params[:order][:shipping])`.